# Run main class from classes?

Tags: java, netbeans

[image]

Hi,there,

how can I run main() method from netbeans by setting the configurations?

EDIT:my VMach is a .class file how can I run it?

Answer (score 1):

Set the main Class: RightClick over project > Run

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [THIS](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html). I think little bit of googling will help you. As well as watching videos on Youtube for using the IDE. Also reading and researching about the IDE you are using. No need to post question on SO.

Comment: Aplogies,
i mean my Vmach.class is a class file hence I can't run the files

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've set your main project correctly, simply press F6